# Store command response to a variable in Github action

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to store the response of aws-cli command to a variable. I am using this:

```
- name: Check if certificate exists
  id: check_certificate
  run: echo "::set-output name=S3_RESPONSE::$(aws s3api head-object --bucket test-bucket-ssl --key fullchain.pem)"
- name: Print vars
  run: echo "${{steps.check_certificate.outputs.S3_RESPONSE}}"
```

I am getting blank output even though the S3 API returns a one-line response. If I use a simple command like "echo" instead of AWS command then it works.

Comment: Did you try dividing the command in two commands to check the output? Example: Set the response in a variable first (`RESPONSE=echo $(aws ...)`), and then use the variable in the `::set-output` using the $RESPONSE variable (`:: $(echo $RESPONSE)`).

Comment: @GuiFalourd This worked as it was using stderr.

      - name: Check if certificate exists
        id: check_certificate
        run: |
          API_RESPONSE=$(aws s3api head-object --bucket test-bucket-ssl --key fullchain.pem 2>&1 | tee true)
          echo "::set-output name=S3_RESPONSE::$(echo $API_RESPONSE)"
          echo "response is: ${API_RESPONSE}"





S3_RESPONSE is set but    echo "response is: ${API_RESPONSE}" doesn't print API_RESPONSE value.